# Date to Age Diff() errors in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I'm falling between two errors while converting a date from datetimepicker to user's age.

Here's my datetimepicker that yields a value of mm/dd/yyyy:

```
<div class="form-group date-time-picker label-floating is-empty">
  <label class="control-label">Birthday</label>
  <input name="datetimepicker" id="datetimepicker" required>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <svg class="calendar-icon"><use xlink:href="icons/icons.svg#calendar-icon"></use></<svg>
  </span>
</div>
```

and the PHP to handle the user input is:

```
// $dob = new DateTime('datetimepicker');
$dob = date('m-d-Y', 'datetimepicker');
$now = new DateTime();
$age = $dob->diff($now);
$agv = $age->format('%Y');
```

$agv should be equal to user's age in years.

Now if I'm using it as it is, I get error:

**Warning:  date() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given**

and if I replaced the first line with the statement in the comment it passes through and the error appear at the diff() as:

**Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (datetimepicker) at position 0 (d): The timezone could not be found in the database.**

Sorry for my coding mistakes but I can't really understand how this part works. It worked fine before I convert to AJAX. Would you please help with?

Comment: You can't mix `DateTime()` objects with strings produced by `date()`. Also, `datetimepicker`isn't a valid value at any time for `date()` or `DateTime()`.

Comment: "Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given".  Did you read the error?  It is pretty clear what the problem is.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to access the actual value of the datetimepicker not the string datetimepicker e.g. use `$_REQUEST['datetimepicker']`?

Comment: @JohnConde thank you for that, it makes it more clearer now. How to strip the date out of the datetimepicker then?

Comment: @PatrickQ actually I did and dig around for it but I couldn't get it to be int.

Comment: @FMeshreky What kind of value does the time picker provide? Is it a Unix timestamp? A date string? Can you give an example? It would make this easier to answer if we knew.

Comment: @apokryfos yes that's true but would post method work with AJAX? I'll give it a try. Thank you :)

Comment: @JohnConde the output of the datetimepicker as mentioned in the js is mm/dd/yyyy as a date string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you cannot mix `DateTime()` with date strings (or unix timestamps). Additionally, you need to refer to the actual submitted value from the datepicker and not just its name.

```
$dob = new DateTime($_POST['datetimepicker']);
$now = new DateTime();
$age = $dob->diff($now);
$agv = $age->format('%Y');
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/909497)**

```
$_POST['datetimepicker'] = '12/31/2018'; // stub this for our example

$dob = new DateTime($_POST['datetimepicker']);
$now = new DateTime();
$age = $dob->diff($now);
$agv = $age->format('%Y');

echo $agv; // 01
```

Comment: Thank you John, I forgot to mention that datetimepicker is located in a different file `index.html` while the php code is in process.php. How do you think I could reach it. I got error `Notice: Undefined index: datetimepicker`

Comment: Please ignore my last comment, I found the bug and your code is now working well with AJAX but without the POST method.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert from string to time (integer value of seconds from EPOCH) before you can use date() function, here is an example:

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
    <label>Birthdate</label>
    <input type="date" name="dob" required>
    <input type="submit" name="form_submit"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['dob'])){
    $dob = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($_POST['dob']));
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Alternatively, you could convert to a DateTime object like so:

```
if(isset($_POST['dob'])){
    $dob = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $_POST['dob']);
    echo $dob->format('m-d-Y');
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/refs.calendar.php

Comment: Thank you, I will apply it now and let you know. Very much appreciated :)

Comment: Note that strtotime assumes certain date formats based on commonly used formats... so 9/10 times it is safer to use DateTime::createFromFormat() as you can specify format.

Comment: Thank you Philip, I'm actually using AJAX not the form submit anymore. It was working fine while using the form but now it got little complicated for me. Thank you anyways for your help attempt.